# Implementing WHERE in an SQLite INSERT command - Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite, addition, where-clause

I'm familiar with Oracle SQL/PL, but not with SQLite, I have managed to construct my database, with an addition operation. I was however wondering how I could implement a WHERE condition for adding data later on to a specific row.
Here is my addition code:

```
public void putInformation(DatabaseOperations dop, String name, String pass, String email){
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME, name);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS, pass);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL, email);
    long k = SQ.insert(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME,null, cv);
    Log.d("Database Operations", "One Raw Inserted");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for an UPDATE query:

```
public void updateInformation(DatabaseOperations dop, String name, String pass, String email){
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME, name);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS, pass);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL, email);
    long k = SQ.update(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, cv, TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME+"=?",new String[]{name});
    Log.d("Database Operations", k+" Rows Updated");
}
```

[SQLiteDatabase.update docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))

Comment: no he is not looking for update query. it is possible to have a where clause in insert query.

Comment: I just found from this from your link. "The second form of the INSERT statement contains a SELECT statement instead of a VALUES clause. A new entry is inserted into the table for each row of data returned by executing the SELECT statement. If a column-list is specified, the number of columns in the result of the SELECT must be the same as the number of items in the column-list.... Any SELECT statement, including compound SELECTs and SELECT statements with ORDER BY and/or LIMIT clauses, may be used in an INSERT statement of this form." Anyway, nice link man :)

Comment: :) ohh, i see your point now. Still i don't think that's what the OP was trying to achieve

Comment: OP first mentioned he is from Oracle SQL/PL background, which makes me assumed that actually he is expecting this form to insert. :)

Comment: Can you explain to me what parameters are meant to go into the update() method? I understand the TABLE_NAME and cv, but what are the other two?

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE condition for adding data later on to a specific row`. If I understand correctly then it will be update for sqlite database. For that you can refer below code.

```
public void updateInformation(DatabaseOperations dop, String name, String pass, String email){
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME, name);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS, pass);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL, email);
    long index = SQ.update(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, cv, TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME+"=?", new String[] {name});
}
```

Comment: no he is not looking for update query. it is possible to have a where clause in insert query.

Comment: I doubt we have insert query with where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `WHERE` condition on insert query. `WHERE condition for adding data later on to a specific row.` For this you can use `UPDATE` query.

**LINKS:**

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_update_query.htm

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/06/edit-row-in-sqlite-database-using.html